# proxy settings in plesk server

Tags: tomcat, proxy, plesk

Actually I am installing the Java script in plesk server

I have installed the tomcat /usr/local/tomcat6/webapps and i deployed the script successfully but when I access my domain domainname.com it is showing apache default page

So for that I have edited my conf file in this path

/var/www/vhosts/domainname/conf/13777576500.44543900_httpd.include

ProxyPreserveHost On

    SuexecUserGroup "proma" "psacln"

```
ServerAdmin  "test@gmail.com"
```

## DocumentRoot "/var/www/vhosts/domainname/httpdocs"

ProxyPass / http://`ipaddress`:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://`ipaddress`:8080/

After that I restarted the server and site is pointing to tomcat and script working perfectly.

If again I restarted the server then the conf file is override and all the changes I have made is lost

I tried to create the vhost.conf file but that also not working.

Please help me

Comment: Where did you create vhost.conf ? it should be /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf/ or /var/www/vhosts/system/domain.com/conf/ (depend on plesk version)  Did you run /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain <youdomainhere> after that?

Comment: I created in /var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf/vhost.conf file

Comment: Yes I ran the /usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain <youdomainhere>

Comment: It's strange, i've checked that it works on my 11.0.9, there line Include "/var/www/vhosts/domain.tld/conf/vhost.conf*" appears in VirtualHost for 80 port. What plesk version you have?

Comment: Hello oleg, thanks for your help now it is working. I used the command you said and it is working thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

To apply new custom `vhost.conf` after creation there is need to run following command:

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/sbin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain <youdomainhere>
```

Custom vhost.conf have to be placed at

for version before 11.5.30:

```
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com/conf/
```

for 11.5.30:

```
/var/www/vhosts/system/domain.com/conf/
```